# Permutation test with imbalanced samples

Tags: permutation-test, familywise-error

Power is a function of sample size. Significant findings are more likely if the sample size is large. With multiple comparisons, permutation testing gives an efficient significance level that maintains a nominal 0.05 family-wise type 1 error rate. The usual alternative, Bonferroni, is inefficient when tests are highly correlated.

However, in analyzing two (or more) separate outcomes or exposures, there may varying levels of missingness. Suppose for instance, $Y_1$ is available on the whole sample whereas $Y_2$ is 50% missing. Then the analysis of $Y_1$ is far more powered. As a consequence, the significance threshold of $Y_1$ will be much more stringent, and as a leading marker, will (in a sense) constitute the entire alpha spending.

The usual approach of obtaining a significance level will be conservative using complete case analysis to each permutated dataset. What is desired is to produce p-values that vary as a function of sample size so that separate significance cut-offs are obtained. This should yield a *more* stringent cut-off for the most complete markers and less stringent cut offs for subsequent missingness.

Has this topic been explored before and/or are there any findings?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're getting at with the last sentence of your second paragraph. It feels like there's missing context

Comment: @Glen_b It is an involved question. What don't you understand? Under the null, the FWER will be 5% (suppose). Of those 5% cases, will the majority of them be rejected from the marker(s) with the most complete data? Are there different significance thresholds you could use for markers with greater missingness to increase power under alternatives?

Comment: 1. "The significance threshold of $Y_1$" - what's this? 2. "leading marker" - what's that? Are we discussing genome studies or something? 3. "alpha spending" - what does this refer to? Is that sequential analysis maybe? It feels like there's something you think we should know but I have no clear idea what you're discussing and some of the jargon is not clear to me. It would be nice to understand what that sentence is about. But the rest of the post seemed clear enough (aside from in what sense a significance level is said to be efficient, but I forgot to ask about it when I hit paragraph 2).

Comment: Anyhow, it feels like you left out some context in that second paragraph. Or possibly it's just my own ignorance of something, but I have no clear idea what you're saying there.